# How do I import inet or uudi data as null from csv file?

Tags: postgresql, excel-formula, postgresql-9.4, postgresql-9.5, dbeaver

I am using DBeaver tool for import csv file into postgres database. When Iam trying to import csv file which is having column (inet datatype) as null. Then I am getting the below error. Please let me know how to fix this in excel ?

```
Error occurred during SQL query execution
```

Reason:
SQL Error [22P02]: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type integer: ""
Position: 468

Comment: Are you really using 3 different [unsupported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) Postgres versions?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the exact command you use to import the CSV file.  [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)